# Private Paypal usage via vue.js

Tags: vue.js, paypal

I want to add PayPal to my vue.js frontend to to enable Transactions between private users. But I dont want any centralised instance for implementing this feature. I just need to create a transaction between two mail-addresses. Is there any opportunity to implement this without using npm vue-paypal-checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation with samples for integrating PayPal Checkout with vue [can be found here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/#vue)

For user-to-user payments, in the order create request [set a `payee` object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/) to the email_address (or merchant_id [from PayPal.com](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness)) of the account that is to receive the payment.

Comment: Thank you but this is the case i was mentioning, where you have to create the whole thing via PayPal Business Account. Seems there is no way round. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Using `payee` is for a direct payment between two other PayPal accounts (users). The only thing you create is an order object for the payment approval.